# Images not showing when running for loop to fetch images

Tags: python, django

I have a for loop in my `index.html` file to dynamically fetch images from the images folder for three objects.

But it is only fetching the first image, with that missing image icon showing on the server for the other two 'destination' objects. Is there anything standing out as amiss in the `index.html` and `views.py` files?

All three images were showing when they were hardcoded and are all present in the images folder. It's since I introduced the `{% static "images" as baseUrl %}` and the `for loop` that it doesn't work.
It's just odd that it does indeed load the first image, but not image 2 and image 3.

I also tried:
`src = "static/images/{{dest.img}}"` instead of `src = "{% static  'images/{{dest.img}}' %}` and this didn't work.

Here is the `for loop` code with the top imports in `index.html`:

```
{% load static %}
{% static "images" as baseUrl %}


                {% for dest in dests %}

                <!-- Destination -->
                <div class="destination item">
                    <div class="destination_image">
                        <img src="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest.img}}" alt="">
                        <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="destination_content">
                        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
                        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{dest.desc}}</p></div>
                        <div class="destination_price">From ${{dest.price}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
```

**In my views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination


def index(request):

    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.name = 'New York'
    dest1.desc = 'City that never sleeps'
    dest1.img = 'destination_1.jpg'
    dest1.price = 500

    dest2 = Destination()
    dest2.name = 'Mumbai'
    dest2.desc = 'Great nightlife'
    dest1.img = 'destination_2.jpg'
    dest2.price = 800

    dest3 = Destination()
    dest3.name = 'Paris'
    dest3.desc = 'The City Of Culinary Delights'
    dest1.img = 'destination_3.jpg'
    dest3.price = 700

    dests = [dest1, dest2, dest3]
    #     'dest1': dest1,
    #     'dest2': dest2,
    #     'dest3': dest3,
    # }

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'dests': dests})
```

Comment: is anything else from dest2 and dest3 rendered as supposed to?

Comment: Yes, the subtitle, price, etc. all there for dest2 and dest3. Just the image not showing.

Comment: Ok. Could you please inspect the rendered html in your dev tools and post the image part? Then we can debug the img src's and see what is wrong

Comment: It says it failed to load the images resource when I click on errors for the entire page. I will check the individual image now for image2. <img src="static/images/" alt=""> is on the image line.

Comment: Ok then the src is not correct. Go ahead and investigate the src which is rendered in your html when visiting the site. Then you will see what is wrong with the src string

Comment: It says <img src="static/images/" alt=""> which is the correct folder and the first image is being grabbed from there. But the src for the first image is showing as: "static/images/destination_3.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, the variable assignments were buggy. That's why it didn't return any string for `{{dest.img}}` and thus couldn't link to the images. You assigned `dest1.img` multiple. See fixed solution:

```
def index(request):

    dest1 = Destination()
    dest1.name = 'New York'
    dest1.desc = 'City that never sleeps'
    dest1.img = 'destination_1.jpg'
    dest1.price = 500

    dest2 = Destination()
    dest2.name = 'Mumbai'
    dest2.desc = 'Great nightlife'
    dest2.img = 'destination_2.jpg' # wrong variable assignment
    dest2.price = 800

    dest3 = Destination()
    dest3.name = 'Paris'
    dest3.desc = 'The City Of Culinary Delights'
    dest3.img = 'destination_3.jpg' # wrong variable assignment
    dest3.price = 700

    dests = [dest1, dest2, dest3]
    #     'dest1': dest1,
    #     'dest2': dest2,
    #     'dest3': dest3,
    # }

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'dests': dests})
```

Comment: How are they buggy? Do you mean I have to delete them?

Comment: @cheznead no, just copy my code and compare the two lines with yours. ;)

Answer (score 1):

if your image is uploaded you could not fetch it like this `dest.img` just do it like `dest.img.url` and there is no need of loading this `{% static "images" as baseUrl %}`
because this is used when you are reflecting images from static but when you start work on database and you are uploading images you have to do it like the following one

```
{% load static %}

                {% for dest in dests %}

                <!-- Destination -->
                <div class="destination item">
                    <div class="destination_image">
                        <img src="{{dest.img.url}}" alt="">
                        <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a href="#">Special Offer</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="destination_content">
                        <div class="destination_title"><a href="destinations.html">{{dest.name}}</a></div>
                        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{dest.desc}}</p></div>
                        <div class="destination_price">From ${{dest.price}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
```

and if this doesn't help you please let me know if there could be any further help

Comment: I tried this just now but it's not showing any images at all when I replace the old static code with dest.img.url.

Comment: is your image coming from uploaded images or from the static files you collected

Comment: The images have been coming from the static files that were collected. But I see the direction you are going with this in terms of later on when images would be uploaded rather than set in static and appreciate the help.